# run jar on mac with arguments

Tags: java, macos, executable

I have a bioinformatics related tool can be found [here](http://www.fda.gov/ScienceResearch/BioinformaticsTools/Mold2/ucm143513.htm). The tool can be download from the link under [that page](http://www.fda.gov/downloads/ScienceResearch/BioinformaticsTools/Mold2/UCM162843.zip).

It is a Java packaged files for which on Windows I can run 
a compiled version (see the readme, need to change name of `Mold2.doc` to `Mold2.exe`) using the following command line:

```
Mold2 -i TestCompounds.sdf
```

(I have moved the `TestCompounds.sdf` file to same path as that exe)

It will produce some message and output 2 files `output.txt` and `report.txt`.

The trouble is that this package doesn't have any pre-compiled version executable for Mac OS.

However, since Java is supposedly cross-platform and since I also have the java Mold2.jar file, I think it would work for me if I can execute under Mac OS. But I can find the way how to do that...

I have tried with:

```
java -cp Mold2.jar Mold2
```

But it only invoke the GUI, and I can't find how to execute this program with only arguments under terminal without invoking the GUI, which is what I want is for integration purpose.

So how can I run this tool on Mac OS on terminal?

Comment: did you try `java -jar Mold2.jar -i TestCompounds.sdf`?

Comment: @Gilles I have tried before.
This results in following error message
`Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile Mold2.jar`

Comment: Sorry for my stupid.
I find that this jar is only a GUI layout. The core of the program is C/C++ and the author doesn't release the source code.So what I can do is only waiting for release for mac version or I need to try some kinds of methods of cross-platform